# image corrupted when I run imagemagick convert inside node.js with exec and then pipe the result to a file

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Here is a test program called `test-program.js` where I run an imagemagick command, and try print stdout of the command to stdout of this program, and then save it to a file:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async function() {
  const cmd = `convert -background red -fill black -gravity center -size 50x50 label:':)' jpg:-`;
  const result = await exec(cmd);
  console.log(result.stdout);
})();
```

I try to run it like this

```
node test-program.js > test.jpg
```

and the jpg will not open

[image]

However, if I run it right on the command line like this:

```
convert -background red -fill black -gravity center -size 50x50 label:':)' jpg:- > test.jpg
```

[image]
the jpg is fine

here are two versions of the program that *do* work as expected:

call command with node, but make the command write directly to the file

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async function() {
  const cmd = `convert -background red -fill black -gravity center -size 50x50 label:':)' test.jpg`;
  const result = await exec(cmd);
  console.log(result.stdout);
})();
```

just write 'hello' into the file with a simpler command:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async function() {
  const cmd = `echo hello`;
  const result = await exec(cmd);
  console.log(result.stdout);
})();
```

So I am pretty sure the command is executing as it should, that it is producing the output it should, and that the wrapper usually writes the output to stdout without a problem. (or maybe with an extra line at the end)

I have also tried converting the string to a buffer with no luck.

Comment: I don't speak `node`, but a quick look at the documentation for `exec()` leads me to think you may need to a) change the *encoding* from its default of *utf8* to *binary* since JPEGs are binary, and maybe b) increase the buffer size. I have no idea **how** to do these things, but maybe someone else can fill in the blanks to get you going... teamwork!

Comment: thanks! I had tried changing to process.stdout.write, but had not thought of changing `exec`

Answer (score 3):

if it helps anybody, two changes are needed to make it work on node 12:

```
const result = await exec(cmd, {encoding: null}); // enconding: null
process.stdout.write(result.stdout); // instead of console log
```

like this:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async function() {
  const cmd = `convert -background red -fill black -gravity center -size 50x50 label:':)' jpg:-`;
  const result = await exec(cmd, {encoding: null});
  process.stdout.write(result.stdout);
})();
```

thanks for your suggestion @mark-setchell

Comment: Well done, and thank you for sharing back with the Stack Overflow community!